# pom.xml игнорируется intellij как пофиксить

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

Делала rebase чтобы собрать все коммиты в один - пропал .iml файл. Восстановила его с помощью просмотра локальной истории в IntellijIDEA. Модуль снова стал подсвечиваться, но вот помник - нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слева видно, что пом серый и зачеркнутый, а справа восстановленный iml файл. Как починить?

Answer (score 2):

правой кнопкой мыши на pom -> maven -> unignore Projects

Answer (score 0):

кое-как получилось

1. Удалила помник
2. Отменила удаление
3. Проблемный модуль - правая кнопка мыши - add framework support - maven